# CM3 power-up - 3V3, 1V8 sequencing

Tags: power

We are developing a high volume product using a lot of CM3s and we're looking into some power-up sequencing issues. I found the following on one of the forums from 2014 (I assume it refers to the CM1). From [Powering the compute module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=74733):

> So the minimum supplies are 1V8 and 3V3. You need to sequence the
>   supplies so that 3V3 comes up at exactly the same time or before 1V8
>   (you can see on the CMIO schematic that the EN2 pin of the SMPS has an
>   RC delay ensuring 1V8 comes up after 3V3).
>
> James Adams (Raspberry Pi - COO & Hardware Lead)

Is this still an important consideration for the CM3s?

And as a side question, what cores do the two rails power? Can the CM3 run on 3v3 alone for a short time at boot; enough to sequence the other rails properly with GPIO under f/w control?

Answer (score 1):

From the latest (Jan 2019) CM3+ datasheet  (section 7.1) - https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/datasheets/rpi_DATA_CM3plus_1p0.pdf

> Supplies should be staggered so that the highest voltage comes up
>   first, then the remaining voltages in descending order. This is to
>   avoid forward biasing internal (on-chip) diodes between supplies, and
>   causing latch-up. Alternatively supplies can be synchronised to come
>   up at exactly the same time as long as at no point a lower voltage
>   supply rail voltage exceeds a higher voltage supply rail voltage.

I'm similarly designing a volume product using the CM3(+). I'm using a 1V8 LDO from the output of a 3V3 DC/DC Buck circuit, so planning to have an RC circuit from the 3V3 to drive the 1V8 enable pin, to give a delay of 5-10ms. This is about how long it takes the 3V3 buck to rise from 1.5V (the enable threshold of the 1V8) to the full 3.3V. But I will refine at prototype stage once I can see oscilloscope plots.